# PHP modifies web-display events from Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)

Tags: php, asterisk

I want to filter event from Asterisk Manager Interface to display only calling and called information on a PHP-webpage.
Here is code and it displays nothing. I have tried this modified string while loop with normal text and it works well.

```
<?php

$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$socket){
     echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
              }
  else{
fputs($socket, "action: login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "username: asterisk\r\n");
fputs($socket, "secret: zxczxc\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "action: Waitevent\r\n");
$wrets=fgets($socket,128);

while(($buffer = fgets($socket,4096)) !== false)
  { $p1=strpos($buffer,"Newchannel");
    if($p1 > 0)
    echo "Calling ID =";
    echo substr($buffer,$p1+4,4);
   }  
 }
}
?>
```

here is the result without modifying event:

[image]

Comment: So what is problem? find bug in your code - offtopic here, see rules.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. Sorry I am newbie and I am still not clear. My problem is using while loop to modify AMI events does not work . web-page displays nothing when I access. I have tried this while loop with normal text file to modify text, it works well.

Comment: Nobody will debug that for you, sorry. Do output of messages to log files, do output of your actions, see all results.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on NodeJS and use module Nami it's a great Event Listener .
the Nami repo is here https://github.com/marcelog/Nami.